# Extract Dataframe from multiple JSONs in a file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset in a `example.txt` file containing about 80k rows. Its format is like this

```json
{..., "text": ..., "class": ..., ...}
{..., "text": ..., "class": ..., ...}
{..., "text": ..., "class": ..., ...}
```

The JSONs do not have any commas between them. What I want to do is to extract the `text` and `class` columns to a `Pandas` DataFrame to look like this:

| Text | Class |
| --- | --- |
| Text1 | Class1 |
| Text2 | Class2 |

How can I do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) with `lines=True` (as this format of JSON is called, not surprisingly, [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/)):

```
df = pd.read_json('path/to/your/file.json', lines=True)[['text', 'class']]
```